# Artifactory LDAP integration issue

Tags: authentication, ldap, artifactory

The Artifactory LDAP/Active Directory integration all working fine.  The only thing is, when the user is removed from the Active Directory group, I notice the user can still log into Artifactory.  I don't have the auto-create user selected in LDAP setup, and don't see the user in the User page in Artifactory.  My understandin is, if the user isn't in the group, he/she won't be able to log in and perform certain tasks, based on the permission given.

Comment: If the user is just removed from an AD group, but still exists on the LDAP server, they'd still be able to log in, I'd expect. They just would no longer have the permissions from that group, since they no longer belong to it.

Comment: @DarthFennec How do I set up so that once a user is removed from the AD group, he/she can't get in at all?

Comment: I don't think you can, just like you can't prevent a user from logging in by just deleting them from an Artifactory group. Is there a reason you don't want to just delete the user from AD? Or disable the user?

Comment: The user is still in the company but his access is to be removed from Artifactory.  In this case, we just want to remove this user ID from the AD group, but not from AD.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a single group that controls access to Artifactory, you could check for group membership in the user search filter. Something like

```
(&(objectClass=peron)(memberOf=cn=Artifactory Users,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com))
```

Would restrict the returned list of users to *only* members of the Artifaactory Users group. This can be done with multiple groups as well using an OR operator in the filter

```
(&(objectClass=peron)(|(memberOf=cn=Other Artifactory Users,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)(memberOf=cn=Artifactory Users,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)...(memberOf=cn=Even More Artifactory Users,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com)))
```

These filters will not handle nested groups (i.e. I am a member of "IT Staff" and "IT Staff" is a member of "Artifactory Users" ... I'm not going to show up as a valid user). See [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ADSI/search-filter-syntax) if you need to handle nested group membership.

Comment: Hello LisaJ - Thanks for the information.  I tried this by placing the following in the "Search Filter" field under "LDAP Settings" (by the way, "User DN Pattern" field and 'Search Base" are left blank, and I got an error complaining authentication fails for a user.  The user is in the 'artifactory-users' AD group: (&(objectClass=person)(memberOf=cn=artifactory-users,ou=Groups,ou=Security Groups,dc=xxx,dc=yyy,dc=zzz))